# PHPUnit creating weird log output with duplicate TestSuite hierarchy in XML

Tags: laravel, phpunit

**Side notes:**

*My PHPUnit version is:* "PHPUnit 4.7.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors."

It came with the Laravel package from composer

---

**Context:**

When i call the following command line:

```
phpunit --log-junit "C:\Users\James\Documents\Test Logs\log.xml" --configuration "C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\phpunit.xml"
```

With the following phpunit.xml defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
            <exclude>./tests/vomit/</exclude>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Shooblie ma hooblie">
            <directory>./tests/vomit/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">app/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

I get the following output: http://pastebin.com/aD4tq7tC

**Problem:**

To save you having to look, *I'm getting multiple levels of "testsuite" which does not follow the documentation output.* What might be going wrong... or is this normal behaviour?

For example (shortened for brevity):

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite>        
        <testsuite>                 
            <testsuite>   
                <testcase></testcase>     
            </testsuite>    
        </testsuite>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

---

*source:* https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/logging.html#logging.xml

Comment: Can i word this any better? Anything i can add to help solve the issue?

Comment: Is there another way to produce an XML representation of which tests were run through the command line in a way that actually works?